# How can I prove this inequality: $\frac{a^2}{3}+b^2+c^2>ab+bc+ca$?

Tags: inequality

If $abc=1$ and $a^3>36$ prove that,

$\frac{a^2}{3}+b^2+c^2>ab+bc+ca$

> I tried to use the general proof method.
>
> $\frac{a^2}{3}+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca>0$

Symbolically notation:

$\frac{a^2}{3}+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca>0 \Rightarrow(x+y+z+...)^2>0$

But, after trying too much, I accepted the defeat.

Comment: are $$a,b,c$$ assumed to be positive?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner a is positive and b c have same sign ...at least

Answer (score 13):

As an old (not too old) Olympiad participant, I love the questions of Proof. My reputation is very low right now.But, I think the proof is correct.

\begin{align}\frac{a^2}{3}+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca&=\frac{a^2}{4}+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca+\frac{a^2}{12}\\
&=\left({\frac a2-b-c}\right)^2+\frac{a^2}{12}-3bc\\
&=\left({\frac a2-b-c}\right)^2+\frac{a^2}{12}-\frac 3a\\
&=\left({\frac a2-b-c}\right)^2+\frac{a^3-36}{12a}\\
&>0
\end{align}

Done.

Comment: Great solution +1

Comment: Obviously you used $a>0$, which is true because $a^{3}>36$.

Comment: @user236182 yes, of course, this is clear..

Answer (score 1):

I remember I solved this inequality a few years ago. Here is my proof. It may look complicated but the idea is actually very simple - we want to make $b,c$ closer to each other keeping the inequality $a^2\ge 36bc$ valid and the sum $b^2+c^2$ fixed so the lefthandside remains fixed and the righthandside increases. The process of making $b,c$ closer to each other will terminate either in the moment when $36bc$ becomes equal to $a^2$ (this corresponds to the second case below) or when $b=c$ (this is the first case).

Let $d=\sqrt{\frac{b^2+c^2}2}$ so that $2d^2=b^2+c^2$. Observe that $d^2 = \frac{b^2+c^2}2 \ge bc$ and $2d = \sqrt{2(b^2+c^2)}\ge b+c$. Thus $$d^2+2ad \ge bc+a(b+c)=ab+bc+ca.$$ 
It is enough to prove that $$\frac{a^2}3+2d^2 > d^2+2ad.$$
This is true if $a\ge 6d$ because $$\frac{a^2}3+2d^2 - (d^2+2ad) = \frac{a(a-6d)}{3}+d^2>0.$$

We are left with the case $a<6d$.

Due to $a<6d$ there are $m,n>0$ such that $m^2+n^2=2d^2$ and $36mn=a^2$. Then $36bc<a^2=36mn$ so $bc<mn$ and also $$b+c=\sqrt{b^2+2bc+c^2}=\sqrt{2d^2+2bc}<\sqrt{2d^2+2mn}=\sqrt{m^2+2mn+n^2}=m+n.$$
It follows that $$ab+bc+ca=a(b+c)+bc<a(m+n)+mn=6(m+n)\sqrt{mn}+mn$$
so we only have to prove that $$\frac{a^2}3+b^2+c^2=12mn + n^2+m^2 \ge 6(m+n)\sqrt{mn} + mn,$$
which is true because $$12mn + n^2+m^2 - (6(m+n)\sqrt{mn} + mn) = (m+n-3\sqrt{mn})^2\ge 0.$$